# X11 Forwarding or X11 Forwarding like solution between two Windows Machines instead of RDP?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access, x11-forwarding

On my new workplace we got two Windows computers, one for development (stationary at office) and a laptop (e.g. for remote usage or meetings).

I have a difficult time to get accustomed to the Windows Remote Desktop Connection (RDC) solution. I miss the option to have one desktop to mess with - the local one, and have **remote applications' windows** in separate local windows, rather than a **remote desktop** in a single window, in the same way as I used to have at my previous work, where my development workstation was running Ubuntu and the laptop was running Windows.

Back then I ot the best of two worlds - Linux for development and hasslefree use of Windows with all working drivers and fresh UI. But also what I miss the most, is having remote applications in separate windows instead of the whole remote desktop in a single window, since it allowed better and more seamless utilization of multiple monitors setup whether at work or at home!

I am wondering if there is a X11 Forward solution or any X11 Forward-like solutions between two Windows machines, so that I can get standalone windows for applications on the remote machines rather than a single window for the whole remote desktop?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "X11 Forward solution" for Windows, because the Windows GUI system is not X11-based. On the other hand, there *is* a seamless/individual window remoting feature in Windows, and it's in fact RDP.

Specifically, you want RDP's "RemoteApp" mode – it allows the client to start a specific program instead of the entire desktop, and its windows will be fully (or *mostly*) integrated with your local windows, with each having a separate taskbar icon and individual stacking order.

RemoteApp server-side support exists even in client editions of Windows<sup>1</sup> and can be activated using the third-party [RemoteApp Tool](http://www.kimknight.net/remoteapptool) (though you need at least Pro or higher, but I'm assuming your workplace has that). You need to define the individual apps you want to run, then create a special `.rdp` link that includes the necessary connection options.

Note that you don't need to pre-define *all* apps – only the *initial* app that you want the .rdp file to launch upon connection, such as Explorer.exe or Windows Terminal. It can however launch further apps without any problems, giving you mostly the same experience as X11 forwarding does.

---

<sup>1</sup> According to [this post](https://www.mydigitallife.net/enable-remoteapp-in-windows-xp-or-vista-to-publish-programs-to-windows-7-virtual-pc-host-with-kb961741-or-kb961742-rail-qfe/), it exists because it was used by Microsoft's own "XP Mode", so its usage is rather legitimate – as long as you're not trying to bypass the "1 active user" constraint. (Note that updates described in that post were only needed for XP/Vista, and later versions such as Windows 10 already come with the necessary files built in.)